# How to add material design icon to JavaFX using codepoint?

Tags: java, javafx

To use material design icons I did the following:

1.Downloaded ttf font from https://materialdesignicons.com/
2.in my css file I added:

```
  @font-face {
    src: url('fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf');
  }
  .icon {
    -fx-font-size: 15px;
    -fx-font-family: 'Material Design Icons';
  }
```

3.Here https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/6.5.95/ I copied the first icon ( mdi-account-lock-open with codepoint F1960) and pasted this icon in my Java code:

[image]

4.After that I added `icon` class to `button` and everything is ok - I have a button with an icon.

The only problem is that in my java code I can't see what icon I use - I have everywhere `empty rectangles`. If it is possible, I would like to add icon using codepoints, for this example codepoint `F1960`. I tried

```
private final Button button = new Button("\uF1960");
```

but it didn't work. Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: Java characters are [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) values.  You cannot directly embed F1960 in a String, but you can write `String.format("%c", 0xF1960)`, or you can directly specify the UTF-16 values: `"\udb86\udd60"`

Comment: Maybe use [ikonli](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java characters are [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) values.  You cannot directly embed U+F1960 in a String, because Unicode `\u` escapes must be followed by exactly four hex digits.

Characters with codepoint values above FFFF are called supplementary characters.  UTF-16 represents such a character using a *surrogate pair,* which is a sequence of two characters from a reserved section of the Unicode repertoire.

You can represent U+F1960 in a String literal as its surrogate pair: `"\udb86\udd60"`

An alternative approach that’s easier to remember is `String.format("%c", 0xF1960)`.  The underlying java.util.Formatter is documented as allowing an Integer argument for `%c`, and unlike characters, an Integer can be larger than 16 bits.

Answer (score -1):

For icons I'd propose to use [ikonli](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/). It provides the best integration of a lot of icon fonts into JavaFX that i know.

The specific set you are looking for seems to be this one: [materialdesign2](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/cheat-sheet-materialdesign2.html)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.  It does not answer the question.

Comment: I prefer the suggestion in this answer to the accepted approach.